# Database fields classing with defined classes (class design troubles)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, class

My database is relational so I have a CategoryID property in my products table and 
categoryName and categoryID in my Category table and class.

my problem is that sometimes when i query my tables I bring back different results. 
For example in my category table I bring back the categoryName from the category Id in my products table.

So, now I have a categoryName in my product class with no property called categoryName.

I have two solutions, just add random properties to my product class holding the names of category name and merchant name,
deppending on the values I bring back or create another class with the values I bring back from the query.
Both which i think is a bad way of doing this.

for example

**product class**
product id
merchant id
product name

**category class**
product id
product name

**merchant class**
merchant id
merchant name

**new class**
category id
category name
product name

i hope i made this as easily as possible to understand.

**My Classes are**

```
public class Product
    {
        public string productId  { get; set;}
        public string productName  { get; set;}
        public string productDescription  { get; set;}
        public string productImage  { get; set;}
        public string trackPrice  { get; set;}
        public string merchantId  { get; set;}
        public string categoryId  { get; set;}
        public int brandId  { get; set;}
    }


public class Brand
        {
            public string brandId { get; set;}
            public string brandName { get; set;}
        }
```

I query my code from the database bringing back just productId, productName, BrandId and BrandName.

Then loop through my records displaying the records in a row. 
I now have values which cross between both classes.

Should I create a new class such as...

```
public class DisplayProducts
    {
        public string productId  { get; set;}
        public string productName  { get; set;}
        public string brandId { get; set;}
        public string brandName { get; set;}
    }
```

or add properties to existing classes?

Comment: My vote goes to "add random properties to my product class"

Comment: I don't quite understand can you show us an example of 'when i query my tables I bring back different results.' I have a fair amount of experience with databases and more recently c# and classes and should be able to help. Please expand / provide example of returned results.

Comment: Sure, here is an example

these classes has the same properties as my tables

class products / product table product name (string) product id (int) category id (int)

class category / category table category id category name

We do a join on products.product id ON Category.category name. So now the values for my product class would be

product name product id category name

thus making my product class properties redundant. Do I create a separate class for these or keep adding properties on to my product class e.g. adding a category name.?

hope thats clearer...

Comment: JamesAndrew, use the _edit_ link, don't post a wall of code in a a comment.